# Internet scraping issue when using vba on secure site

Tags: vba, object, required

I am trying to automate IE to pull data from a secure site how every I keep getting the same error message: "Object required"

The debugger points to the line  -HTMLinput.Value = "test"

Everything before works fine. I don't know what's the problem. I have verified my ID to make sure there is no mistakes.

```
Sub Brows()

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium
    Dim Policy As Object
    Dim certificate As Object
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLinput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "secure website address"
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")

    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
    Set HTMLinput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("input ID")
    HTMLinput.Value = "test"
End Sub
```

Comment: It's because the preceding line wasn't executed successfully. `Set HTMLinput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("input ID")` wasn't set, probably because the element "input ID" wasn't found.

Answer (score 1):

How to log into a web site using Excel and VBA.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub Login_2_Website()

Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = "https://www.google.com/accounts/Login"
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.timeout = 60
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.Document

HTMLDoc.all.Email.Value = "sample@vbadud.com"
HTMLDoc.all.passwd.Value = "*****"

For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next

' oBrowser.Refresh ' Refresh If Needed
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Debug.Assert Err = 0
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

The program requires references to the following:

```
1 Microsoft Internet Controls

2. Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-login-to-website-using-vba.html

Comment: thank you for your help. That still did not work for me. I tried printing all the input tags to confirm their attributes but nothing appeared on the debugger. I also tried to count the inputs but the debugger returned 0.  I don't understand what's going on. I am wondering if it's because it is a secure site that I can't interact with the DOM.

Comment: I am using the libraries you referred to.

Comment: Can you share the URL, or is it behind a firewall?

Comment: It’s behind a firewall unfortunately.

Comment: I figured.  Well...in your code hit the F8 button over and over and over...  This will let you step through each line of code, line by line.  See where the error is; it will be highlighted yellow.  Try to interpret the error.  Copy/paste the error message into Google; do a search and try to figure it out.  You can post the error message here and I'll try to help you a bit more.  I don't know how much more I can do when I don't have access to anything behind that firewall.